# Word for publicising your opinion

Tags: single-word-requests

What is it called when one expresses their entire opinion? Especially when it is not that necessary? (In a casual conversation/party, haughtily)

Answer (score 1):

How about **overshare**? From M-W:

> **[overshare](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overshare)**: to share or reveal too much information

In your example, the person in question is **oversharing** their opinion by expressing it in its entirety when that is not necessary. The other parties to the conversation would likely characterize this person as providing TMI (Too Much Information).